# Как можно защитить дневные ивенты в игре от пользователей, переводящих время на устройстве

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Разрабатываем оффлайн игру.

Одна из особенностей - ивенты. Дневные, месячные и т.п. Как пример, есть ивент, который стартует сначала каждого месяца. За заход в игру даются всякие плюшки. Выглядит как-то так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем больше дней в месяце ты заходил в игру, тем круче награду получаешь.

**Проблема:** человек может переводить время на день вперёд 24 раза и получить награду за весь месяц в первый же день. В онлайн играх такой проблемы нет. Но как предотвратить такие читы в оффлайн игре? Понятное дело, что человек на своём устройстве про большом упорстве может что угодно ломануть в игре.

В данном случае хочется найти алгоритм, который защитит от дилетантских попыток (вроде перевода времени).

P.S. игра на unity3d, но это не важно, алгоритм не привязан к конкретному языку/движку.

Comment: я думаю никак. время нужно брать из сети , а не локально у пользователя, тогда проблемы такой не будет.  Любые оффлайн игры от такой проблемы не защищены. но я бы наверное костыль написал. типо сделал кеш и записывал в него текущую дату и время, а потом сверял при каждом запуске

Comment: @Санаев пишется. Но каким образов вы сравнение будете делать? Если время перевели назад, то ещё можно проверить. Но если вперёд, то без сверки с онлайн времени сложно представить.

Comment: Тогда нужно хотя бы при запуске сверять время с онлайн временем. Без интернета не обойтись

Comment: Если игра - чисто офлайн, то почему возможное читерство - это проблема? Пусть пользователь делает, что хочет. Если же есть какие-то онлайн-элементы (лидерборд, например), то, значит, и проверку можно привязать к онлайну.

Comment: @Yaant есть внутриигровые покупки. Читерство будет вредить монетизации игры.

Comment: может быть есть какой нибудь фоновый таймер (как например в андроиде) .

Comment: То есть, доступ в сеть для игры таки нужен. Значит, вполне можно эвенты привязать к онлайну - нет сети, нет и награды. Есть сеть - проверять время в интернете, и решать, выдавать ли награду.

Comment: @Yaant сеть нужна только для синхронизации. Если человек с одного устройства играет, то нет надобности в интернете. Мы хотим минимизировать функции, которые требуют интернета.

Comment: А как человек докупает платные функции, как игра узнает, что он действительно что то купил ?

Comment: @Mike купить без интернета нельзя, да.

Comment: Это понятно, больше интересно как именно. ну, можете не говорить. Идея в том, что бы программа фиксировала максимальное время на часах, которое видела. Возможно писала куда то свое состояние по дням. В момент когда связь с интернетом появляется и идет процесс оплаты она может сверить часы с сервером и если обнаружит что ее часы уходили вперед откатиться на состояние на допустимый день. Так же, если платные функции действуют определенное время игрок их потеряет если переведет часы вперед слишком сильно

Comment: @Mike ну да, в этот момент сверить можно. Но, максимум, что мы можем теперь сделать, это откатить то, что он начитерил. Но как определить что именно он начитерил? Ну и да, вряд ли читер что-либо будет покупать в игре (: Вы можете спросить: "Не всё ли равно, ведь он всё равно ничего не купит?" Нет, одна из online фич - pvp бои, где у него будет преимущество за счёт полученных за счёт читов ресурсов.

Comment: Но pvp бои опять же подразумевают online. И в этот момент опять же можно проверять был ли чит. А что именно он начитерил вам даже понимать не надо будет, если будете хранить по датам состояние игры. Вы же все равно сохраняете ее состояние, вот и сохраняйте его по датам. В случае чита удаляете все последующие состояния игры и читаете подходящее

Answer (score 2):

Самое надёжное решение тут с использованием интернета. Его на работе и применяем. Всё просто:
- Если соединения нет, то все ивенты недоступны, а вместо них какая-нибудь заглушка вроде "войдите в сеть, чтобы получить доступ к событиям"
- Если интернет есть, то просто берём дату с серверам бэкенда или откуда-нибудь из интернета.